# AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error - APACHE LOG

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am running my AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application

PHP 5.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.4

Every time i got this Warning in my apache log.

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to
>   probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
>   the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I belive could be my .htaccess , this is my code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/?$  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php [NC,L]

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

Any ideia about this error?

Comment: @MrWhite actually my server  answer request from: `https://api.mypage.com/transaction/create`  ,    `https://api.mypage.com/transaction/create/`   `https://api.mypage.com/transaction/create.php`   , if i change all things will be bone?

Comment: @MrWhite  i try you suggestion, but when i try access using the slash like: `/transaction/create/`  i got a error 404.  but works fine wheen i use `https://api.mypage.com/transaction/create`  and `https://api.mypage.com/transaction/create.php`    i remove all and put only  ´ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]´

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$/?$  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php [NC,L]
> ```

Your rule to append the `.php` file extension is incorrect. You are effectively rewriting to a non-existent file... repeatedly. Try the following instead:

```
# Append .php file extension if omitted and destination file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The above states... for any request that does not already have a file-extension, it tests to see if a file exists with the `.php` extension exists before internally  rewriting to it.

There's no need to backslash escape literal dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*, since this is an "ordinary" string (not a regex).